# Does Kubernetes GKE HorizontalPodAutoscaler min and max replicas work on a per zone basis?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I'm looking for clarification regarding HPA in my GKE cluster. I've read these docs https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling but I wanted to know, by setting the `minReplicas` and `maxReplicas` are these the min and max values across all nodes in the cluster or is this the min and max per zone?

For instance if I have a cluster with 3 zones and 2 nodes per zone, and I set `minReplicas=1` and `maxReplicas=3` what will be the min and max number of pods in the entire cluster? Assuming the HPA is operating on a deployment that creates a single node.

Comment: Mininum and maximum number of pods apply to the deployment, so that's the absolute number of the pods.

Answer (score 2):

> `minReplicas=1` and `maxReplicas=3` what will be the min and max number of
>   pods in the entire cluster?

When you setup HPA, you set values per Deployment, so that is values of minimum and maximum number of pods for a Deployment which you manage by HPA.

Simply speaking, HPA will update a value of a `replica` parameter in your deployment. Pods distribution is a responsibility of the scheduler and it's behaviour will be absolutely the same as if you will just scale a number of replicas manually.